# Attempting to prove the following inequality

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, radicals

I got a question on a test to prove the following inequality:

$$
\sqrt{1*2}\space+\space\sqrt{2*3}\space+\space...\space+\space\sqrt{n(n-1)}>\frac{n^2-1}{2} : n>1, n\in\mathbb{N}
$$
I tried to prove this with induction and got to the point where I proved

$$
n=k+1 \\
\sqrt{1*2}\space+\space\sqrt{2*3}\space+\space...\space+\space\sqrt{k(k+1)}>\frac{k^2-1}{2}\space+\sqrt{k(k+1)} \\ 
$$
and I also proved
$$
\frac{(k+1)^2-1}{2} > \frac{k^2-1}{2}\space+\sqrt{k(k+1)}
$$
but I couldn't successfully prove 
$$ \sqrt{1*2}\space+\space\sqrt{2*3}\space+\space...\space+\space\sqrt{k(k+1)}>\frac{(k+1)^2-1}{2}
$$

Comment: This is not correct. (The upper-most statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can prove the **opposite** inequality.

According to GM-AM you have for $n > 1$:
\begin{eqnarray*} \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{i(i+1)}}
& \color{blue}{<} &  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{i + (i+1)}{2} \\
& = &  \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}2i + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 1 \right)\\
& = &  \frac{1}{2}\left(n(n-1) + (n-1)\right)\\
& = &  \color{blue}{\frac{n^2-1}{2}}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

**Edit after comments:**

If you add the next term $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$, then the relation sign changes its direction:

- $\sum_{i=1}^{\color{red}{n}}\sqrt{i(i+1)} \color{red}{>} \frac{n^2-1}{2}$

The proof for this case you can see in Michael Rosenberg's answer.

Comment: but if you try testing it for cases n=2,3 it doesn't work

Comment: @Guysudai1 Did you forget to take the square root? It works!

Comment: but that's different from my question, you are missing the first term / last term

Comment: $n=2$: $\sqrt{2} < \frac{2^2-1}{2} = \frac{3}{2} \Rightarrow$ True!
$n=3$: $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \frac{3^2-1}{2} = 4 \Rightarrow$ True!

Comment: I mean, in the question I have n=2 is $\sqrt(2) + \sqrt(6)$, maybe that's what they meant by n=2? I am confused

Comment: The sum I wrote gives exactly the expression you wrote down. Just expand the sum for $n=2$ and $n=3$ to see this.

Comment: @Guysudai1 I have added an edit to address the inequality you may want to have proved.

Answer (score 1):

By C-S we can get the following estimation.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k^2+k}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}\geq\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k^2+\frac{k}{2}+\frac{k}{2}}{k+\frac{1}{2}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k}{2k+1}=$$
$$=\frac{n^2-n}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k^2}{2k^2+k}\geq\frac{n^2-n}{2}+\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}k\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k^2+k)}=$$
$$=\frac{n^2-n}{2}+\frac{\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right)^2}{\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{3}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}=\frac{n^2-1}{2}\cdot\frac{4n}{4n+1}.$$

Comment: Most probably the OP wanted to prove this inequality. So, I have included a reference to your answer in my one.

Comment: Thank you,  trancelocation. It seems, I got something interesting.